# Research on n-Dimensional Packings of Spheres, in the cube and/or torus?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, geometry, spheres, packing-problem

I'm not entirely certain anyone researches this, but if so, I am having trouble finding papers on it. Was hoping someone might be able to point me towards where to look.

I am up against a problem that I have reduced to optimal- and/or symmetric/regular packings of unit-radius spheres in a cube of edge-length 2, across arbitrary dimensions

There's also a potentially helpful feature, where I can get away with the spheres "wrapping around" through the edges and corners of the cube. To wit, in three dimensions, if I translate a sphere upwards along z until it intersects the boundary of the cube at the z = 1 plane, then whatever subset of the of the sphere lies outside the cube is considered present coming up from the z = -1 plane at the "bottom" of the cube.

Thanks in advance for any direction on this.

Comment: It certainly is a research topic. Many years ago I read that solutions to asymptotically optimal  sphere-packing in higher dimensions had applications in digital data transmissions (e.g. for error-correcting/detecting codes). Sorry I can't recall a reference. It was a Scientific American article, maybe part of Martin Gardiner's monthly Mathematical Games article.